# Ajax url contain data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want design a login form via **PHP + JQuery Ajax.**

I have 2 textbox :

- txtbox1 `id="kadiID"`
- txtbox2 `id="sifreID"`

and button :

- `id="btnGiris"`

My buttons **JQuery** code is:

```
$('#btnGiris').on("click", function(){ 
    var kullaniciID=$("#kadiID").val();
    var sifreID=$("#sifreID").val();
    var cpthcID='';
    if($('#kontrolID').length){ 
        cpthcID=$('#kontrolID').val();
        alert("cpthc: [" + cpthcID + "]");
    }
    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",
        url :'giris.php',
        data:({ kadi : kullaniciID, sifre : sifreID, cpthc : cpthcID }),
        cache:false,
        beforeSend :function()
        {
            // other codes
        },
        success :function(donen_veri){
    alert(donen_veri);
        },
        complete:function()
        {
            // other code
        },
    })
    return false;
})
```

When I click button, my send datas from javascript are not process in giris.php file. Also I opened development tool via F12 and open network tab then I click button I saw a url like this:

**Datas which I send via ajax data field are apear in url:**

[image]

How can I solve this.

Comment: you javascript is working fine. The data are sent to your php file. This part of your code works. But without the other side, we can't help

Comment: Can you please add the php part of the code?

Comment: Maybe you should post it: `type    : "POST",` but without the php we won't know.

Answer (score 1):

I just change

> type: "POST"

instead of

> type: "GET"

in my ajax code, and problem is solved, thanks for everyone, especially [HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr)

Answer (score 0):

this is my php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include '../ayar.php';
$tablo="kullaniciTB";
$durum='';
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
        } else{
        if (empty($_SESSION['count'])) {

            $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
            $durum='count: ' . $_SESSION['count'];
            } else {
            $_SESSION['count']++;
        }
    }
    $kadi = $_POST['kadi'];
    $sifre = $_POST['sifre'];
    if($kadi=='' or $sifre=='') {
        $yazi="xbosx";
    }
    else if(strstr($kadi, '=') or strstr($kadi, '\'') or strstr($kadi, '--')){
        $yazi="yhacky";
    }
    else{
        $cptDurum="";
        if($_SESSION['count']>4){
            $kntrl = $_POST['cpthc'];
            if($kntrl==''){
                $cptDurum="bos";
            }
            else if($kntrl==$_SESSION['sifre']){
                $cptDurum="dogru";
            }
            else if($kntrl!=$_SESSION['sifre']){
                $cptDurum="yanlis";
            }
        }
        if($cptBos=="dogru"){
            $sorgu="SELECT * FROM `" . $tablo . "` WHERE kullaniciAdi='".$kadi."' AND sifre='".$sifre."' AND yetki=1";      
            if ($sonuc = mysqli_query($conn, $sorgu)) {
                /* fetch associative array */
                while ($deger = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sonuc)) {
                    $_SESSION["vaktiGeldi"] = time() + 5400;
                    $_SESSION["login"] = true;
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $kadi;
                    $_SESSION["userID"] = $deger['id'];
                    $durum="kdogruk";
                }                       
                /* free sonuc set */
                mysqli_free_result($sonuc);
            }
        }
        else if($cptDurum=="bos"){
            $durum="cptBos";
        }
        else if($cptDurum=="yanlis"){
            $durum="cptYanlis";
        }
    }
}
else{
    $durum="mzatenm";
}
echo $durum;
```

?>